# Copy one key from one redis instance to another

Tags: redis

I have a Redis implementation with 6 nodes (3 masters 3 slaves - cluster enabled). I have load in every master an amount of keys.

So, my question is:

Is it possible to actual copy one key from 127.0.0.1:30001 to 127.0.0.1:30002?

For example lets say that my key has the name "testkey". If i copy this key from 30001 to 30002, when i want to get the key from 30001 or from 30002 the response must fetch the value of "testkey" in both calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that not how it works.

Keys in the cluster are assigned to hash slots and slots are assigned to master nodes. The keys' assignment is done by hashing their names (or the hash tag in them) so it is consistent, meaning that a given key name always hashes to the same slot.

A key can exist only once in the keyspace, but the slot it belongs to can be moved between masters. To scale reads from that key you can use the slave of the applicable master.

A good point to start understanding how the cluster works is by referring to the [tutorial](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok i understand the assignement of slots. So is it not possible to copy the slot and then the key from 30001 to 30002? Suppose this scenario. I have one key in 30001 that requested by the client many many times. I want to copy this key in 30002 and redirect the half requests in 30002. This is a good strategy in my head!! Is is not?

Comment: You can move the slots around in the cluster, but a key can exist only once in the keyspace. In other words, you can't do that. You could, OTOH, use the slave to read the key from as well.

Comment: Sorry for the spam @Itamar. I have a question. When i try to read a key from a slave (i know that replicates the master with the key i request), he response with moved error. So, it is not possible to read a key directly from slave and fetch value without moved error and redirection to the master? Thank you

Comment: You'll need to invoke the [`READONLY`](http://Redis.io/commands/readonly) command in the connection to slave before trying to read.

Comment: You are a life saver!Thank you!